# Did Tolkien liken Aragorn to a wolf?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, quotes, j-r-r-tolkien

I seem to recall from somewhere that Tolkien likened Aragorn to a type of animal, I think a wolf, but I can't for the life of me remember where he may have said this. Did Tolkien actually make a comparison like this? If so, where did he make this comparison?

Comment: Seems unlikely. The Company fight wolves on at least one occasion.

Comment: I wonder if you actually mean Aragon I, Elessar's great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great grandfather who was slain by a pack of wild wolves in Eriador. Just like Dragons, Tolkien made a clear distinction that Wolves were inherently evil twisted beings, so I doubt that this was the basis of Aragorn's character.

Comment: Could it have been earlier in the books, maybe in the vicinity of Bree? I remember he's described as unkempt, grey-eyed and fresh out of the wilderness, so potentially fairly wolfish. If the comparison is ever actually made, it would probably be around this time, when he is still just Strider to the Hobbits.

Comment: from a quick ctrl+f search of LOTR, none of the references to the word 'wolf' compare Aragorn to one

Answer (score 2):

This is perhaps stretching, but might you be thinking of "Thorongil"? It's the name Aragorn used during his time in Gondor and Rohan, and means "Eagle of the Star":

> Thorongil men called him in Gondor, the Eagle of the Star, for he was swift and keen-eyed, and wore a silver star upon his cloak; but no one knew his true name nor in what land he was born.
>
> <sup>*Return of the King* Appendix A "Annals of the Kings and Rulers" Chapter 1: "The Númenórean Kings" (iv) Gondor and the Heirs of Anárion *The Stewards*</sup>

That Thorongil is Aragorn is revealed in Appendix B:

> **2957-80** Aragorn undertakes his great journeys and errantries. As Thorongil he serves in disguise both Thengel of Rohan and Ecthelion II of Gondor.
>
> <sup>*Return of the King* Appendix B "The Tale of Years" (ii) The Third Age</sup>

It would also be a much more complimentary comparison, since eagles are traditionally associated with Manwë (good) and wolves with Morgoth/Sauron (bad).